# How to use monorepo packages with nestjs using turborepo?

Tags: nestjs, monorepo, turborepo

Here's what a real simple monorepo with nestjs using turborepo looks like:

```
.
├── README.md
├── apps
│   └── nest
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── nest-cli.json
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── src
│       │   ├── app.controller.spec.ts
│       │   ├── app.controller.ts
│       │   ├── app.module.ts
│       │   ├── app.service.ts <---- importing class here
│       │   └── main.ts
│       ├── test
│       │   ├── app.e2e-spec.ts
│       │   └── jest-e2e.json
│       ├── tsconfig.build.json
│       └── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── packages
│   └── lib
│       ├── index.ts <------- exporting class here
│       ├── package.json
│       └── tsconfig.json
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
├── pnpm-workspace.yaml
└── turbo.json
```

A class is defined in `packages/lib/index.ts` and is then imported in `apps/nest/src/app.service.ts`.

But doing so leads to the following error when trying to import this `index.ts`:

```
nest:dev: 
nest:dev: [1:40:25 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
nest:dev: 
nest:dev: /Users/hercule/Workspace/monorepo-nestjs-package/packages/lib/index.ts:3
nest:dev:   public hello() {
nest:dev:          ^^^^^
nest:dev: 
nest:dev: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
nest:dev:     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
nest:dev:     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
nest:dev:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
nest:dev:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
nest:dev:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
nest:dev:     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
nest:dev:     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
nest:dev:     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
nest:dev:     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hercule/Workspace/monorepo-nestjs-package/apps/nest/src/app.service.ts:2:1)
nest:dev:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
```

**Therefore, How do we import a typescript package into nestjs that will be compiled / parsed properly?**

Note 1: I tried importing this lib (`index.ts`) to a ne**x**tjs app and angular app, it works without any issue. The problem only arises with nestjs

Note 2: Above's example can be reproduced using following repository: https://github.com/beneccli/monorepo-nestjs-package, once cloned, at root of the project, simply run `pnpm i` and then `pnpm dev` (or npm or yarn).

Comment: did you find any solution yet for this issue? I'm facing the exact same issue!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually simple.

Issue was that the dependency was not transpiled from typescript to javascript.

To solve this it is required to tell how to build the dependency and where to find the result files. This is done using the `package.json` of the `lib` dependency:

```
// packages/lib/package.json
{
  "name": "lib",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "./dist/index", <----- NEW
  "types": "./dist/index", <----- NEW
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build --force tsconfig.json" <----- NEW
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  }
}
```

I updated the previously given repository accordingly.

What is important here is to not forget to run `pnpm build` after `pnpm install` in order to get the proper built dependency. Then nestjs can be started in either dev or prod.

Comment: but if you run nest app in dev it won't refresh after you update one of the packages correct?

Answer (score 0):

I clone a repo and see the following things in your packages/lib/package.json :

- Your packages ( lib exactly ) does not have a build script so I added one.
- Lib main does not point to the dist/index.js build so I modified the main too.

Final lib's package.json is here

```
{
  "name": "lib",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "types": "./index.ts",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  }
}
```

After those are done, I run the script `pnpm run build` in the root.

Then I run `pnpm dev`, and your apps should start working on `http://localhost:3000/` with the text `Test: Hello World!`

The thing behind that is you should have a build script to compile your Typescript code into JS, then have the main to point exactly the compiled index.
So that when NestJs use your lib, it should have all the functions and classes in it.